# How to show classes in Visual Studio 2010 Professional class diagram in NOT nested way?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, class-diagram

I have a really annoying problem with class diagram in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Here's an example:

[image]

I have the main class called **MyBaseClass** which is inherited by **MyClass** which on the other hand is inherited by **MyComplexClass** written up manually in the code.

While I try to run Class Diagram generator in VS it's presented in the **nested** way in a single "block" of class **Program**.

How can make it look more **tree-like(chart)** with inheritance lines, just like the most popular/standard display of a class diagram?

Comment: 2017 and still looking for an answer to that.